# Gravity Forms should pull some data from mysql

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce, gravity

I am trying to make some sort of password recovery function (don't ask why).

I have a WordPress site and use Gravity Forms to ask for the client's mail address.
Then I want to use that address to find the corresponding woo-commerce product, that has the same email address added as a custom attribute (pa_e-mail).
Then I want to use another attribute, that is holding a password (no need for super strong security, md5, hashes, etc) as a custom attribute (pa_pw) and send that password back to Gravity Forms to send it via mail to the user. Also, I want to send the link to that product, using the permalink.

The code I have so far is inside the functions.php and in Gravity Forms, I have two textfields that can receive dynamic fill. (edit_pw & edit_link)

```
function get_pw_by_email( $email ) {
  // Get all products
  $products = wc_get_products( array(
      'limit' => -1,
      'status' => 'publish', 
  ) );

  // Loop through the products
  foreach ( $products as $product ) {
      // Get the value of the "pa_e-mail" attribute
      $pa_email = $product->get_attribute('pa_e-mail');
      // Check if the "pa_e-mail" attribute matches the email
      if ( $pa_email == $email ) {
          // Get the value of the "pa_pw" attribute
          $pa_pw = $product->get_attribute('pa_pw');
          // Return the value of the "pa_pw" attribute
          return $pa_pw;
          // Break the loop
          break;
      }
  }
}

function get_product_permalink_by_email( $email ) {
  // Get all products
  $products = wc_get_products( array(
      'limit' => -1,
      'status' => 'publish', 
  ) );

  // Loop through the products
  foreach ( $products as $product ) {
      // Get the value of the "pa_e-mail" attribute
      $pa_email = $product->get_attribute('pa_e-mail');
      // Check if the "pa_e-mail" attribute matches the email
      if ( $pa_email == $email ) {
          $permalink = $product->get_permalink();
          // Return the permalink
          return $permalink;
          // Break the loop
          break;
      }
  }
}

add_filter( 'gform_field_value_edit_link', 'my_custom_population_function1' );
function my_custom_population_function1($value) {
  if ( rgpost( 'is_submit_6') ) {
    // Form has been submitted, so retrieve the values from the database
    
    // get mail address from gf field
    $email = rgar($entry, '4');
    
    // Permalink
    $link = get_product_permalink_by_email($email);
    
    // Output the value of $link to the PHP error log
    error_log( 'edit_link: ' . $link );
    
    return $link;
  } else {
    // Form has not been submitted, so return an empty value
    return '';
  }
}

add_filter( 'gform_field_value_edit_pw', 'my_custom_population_function2' );
function my_custom_population_function2($value) {
  if ( rgpost( 'is_submit_6') ) {
    // Form has been submitted, so retrieve the values from the database
    
    // get mail address from gf field
    $email = rgar($entry, '4');
    
    // Password
    $password = get_pw_by_email($email);
    
    // Output the value of $password to the PHP error log
    error_log( 'edit_pw: ' . $password );
    
    return $password;
  } else {
    // Form has not been submitted, so return an empty value
    return '';
  }
}
```

But the mail I receive just has empty values, where I want {Link:6} & {Passwort:7} to appear.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know you say it doesn't matter, but "no need for super strong security" plus the word "password" don't go together. You don't care, which is your right, but I (the user of your site) care. The vast majority of users have poor passwords that they use everywhere. By _you_ storing the password insecurely, you've just potentially leaked someone else's _bank_ or _email_ password. Shame on the user for doing that, true. But the fix is trivial on your side. The only exception _might be_ if you are randomly generating the password and not letting users change it.

Comment: Yes, the password is generated and pre-set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work!
My problem was, that the value of my email field (ID4) was not accessible in the $enrtry variable of my "gform_field_value_" filters.

Here is my working code:

```
function get_product_permalink_by_email($email) {

  $products = get_posts(array('post_type' =>'product', 'tax_query' =>array(array('taxonomy' =>'pa_e-mail', 'field' =>'name', 'terms' =>$email))));

  if (empty($products)) {
    return '';
  }

  return get_permalink($products[0] ->ID);
}

function get_pw_by_email($email) {

  $products = get_posts(array('post_type' =>'product', 'tax_query' =>array(array('taxonomy' =>'pa_e-mail', 'field' =>'name', 'terms' =>$email))));

  $terms = wp_get_post_terms($products[0] ->ID, 'pa_pw', true);
  if (empty($terms)) {
    return '';
  }

  return $terms[0]->name;
}

add_action( 'gform_pre_submission_7', 'pre_submission' );
function pre_submission( $entry, $form ) {
    
    $entry_id = $entry['id'];
    
    global $email;
    $email = $_POST['input_2'];
    
    $edit_link = get_product_permalink_by_email( $email );
    if ( $edit_link ) {
        $edit_link .= 'edit';
    }
    $edit_pw = get_pw_by_email( $email );

    $_POST['input_3'] = $edit_link;
    $_POST['input_4'] = $edit_pw;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have re-written the code.

```
function get_product_permalink_by_email($email) {

  $products = get_posts(array('post_type' = >'product', 'tax_query' = >array(array('taxonomy' = >'pa_e-mail', 'field' = >'name', 'terms' = >$email))));

  if (empty($products)) {
    return '';
  }

  return get_permalink($products[0] - >ID);
}

function get_pw_by_email($email) {

  $products = get_posts(array('post_type' = >'product', 'tax_query' = >array(array('taxonomy' = >'pa_e-mail', 'field' = >'name', 'terms' = >$email))));

  $terms = wp_get_post_terms($products[0] - >ID, 'pa_pw', true);
  if (empty($terms)) {
    return '';
  }

  return $terms[0] - >name;
}

add_filter('gform_field_value_edit_link', 'my_custom_population_function1');
function my_custom_population_function1($value, $entry) {
  // Form has been submitted, so retrieve the values from the database

  // get mail address from gf field
  $email = rgar($entry, '4');

  // Permalink
  $link = get_product_permalink_by_email($email);

  // Output the value of $link to the PHP error log
  error_log('edit_link: '.$link);

  return $link;
}

add_filter('gform_field_value_edit_pw', 'my_custom_population_function2');
function my_custom_population_function2($value, $entry) {
  // Form has been submitted, so retrieve the values from the database

  // get mail address from gf field
  $email = rgar($entry, '4');

  // Password
  $password = get_pw_by_email($email);

  // Output the value of $password to the PHP error log
  error_log('edit_pw: '.$password);

  return $password;

}
```

and I am most certainly sure, that its this line that causes the "error":

```
$email = rgar($entry, '4');
```

If I enter a mail address manually as $email, then it works as expected.
So there must be something about Gravity Forms not passing the value of the e-mail input textfield (ID 4).

Any hint someone?

Answer (score 0):

What if you replace $email = rgar($entry,'4'); with the following:

```
if(GFAPI::entry_exists($entry) == true){
  $get_entry = GFAPI::get_entry($entry);
  $email = $get_entry['4'];
}
```

Comment: No, same outcome. Maybe the input from this field is not ready at this point in time? Some kind of hen and egg problem.